How much weight can a square box tube support vertically dimentions 1x1x1/8wall thickness
How much weight can a steel square box tube one inch by one inch with 1/8 wall thickness support vertically. The support will be 15 feet tall and have two of the tubes with webbing in between.

Could you sketch your idea? The words you’ve used seem internally inconsistent. (Vertical load, and then talking about webbing.)

I really wish "webbing" meant cross bracing here.

Add one more tube (correctly located) and appropriate bracing between all three and you have a triangle truss structure. The described structure will easily turn into a bent mess.

If it was perfectly plumb it would probably support a significant load. HOWEVER  since it's 15 feet long it would easily be susceptible to bending with even the slightest bump and it would lose all its strength leading to a catastrophic failure. I would only use this for decorative purposes only.

I have found the Engineering Toolbox website to be reliable.
https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/euler-column-formula-d_1813.html
The webbing could stabilize in one dimension but won't in both.
I have assumed the best case for end conditions (n = 4).

The moment of Inertia is from here: https://www.calcresource.com/moment-of-inertia-rtube.html
Dynamic loading could increase the effective load by 2-3, maybe more if wind is involved.
As DJ pointed out, this column is thin enough where it could easily be momentarily bent by being bumped leading to a catastrophic failure. If this is safety critical where something could collapse on people, this is not an acceptable design.

Thank you, I am going to use a triangular design to stabilize, but the load is going to be carried by the two 1x1 tubes. This is good information! Thanks again!
